# addClass to a div with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

Hi what i'm trying to do is add a class to a div with specific name attribute,
for example i have a div like this.

```
<div class="box" name="box-1"></div>

<div class="box" name="box-2"></div>
```

now how to add a class to that div with that attribute, i mean add class to a div with name attribute of box-1,
how can i do that?

Comment: Uae the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). However `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute, so the bigger problem is that your HTML is invalid. Use a data attribute instead, ie. `data-name="box-1"`, or better still, an `id`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `div[name ="box-2"]`

```js
$('div[name ="box-2"]').addClass('myclass');
```

```css
.box{width:50px; height:50px;}
.myclass{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" name="box-1">Box 1</div>

<div class="box" name="box-2">Box 2</div>
```